# Android Applications crashes only on first launch only after downloading from Google Play

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, admob, google-play-services

My Application works fine if I install from sdcard using apk file. but on downloading from google play it crashes with toast

> application shortcut is already available.

It crashes only on first session with the error log that I got from google play

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.ads.InstallReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.InstallReceiver" on path: DexPathList

Waiting for the Help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely an Admob problem. Remove

```
<receiver 
  android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver" 
  android:exported="true"> 
  <intent-filter> 
  <action 
  android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

from your Admob Plugin Manifest. Make sure your Ad works after removing that. If the problem  is still there, delete the current Admob plugin folder and install the latest version from [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v3.0.4). Just download only the one title **GoogleMobileAds.unitypackage** and import it into your project.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just after removing these lines from manifest.

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad Nice. Make sure to test the ad by clicking it before declaring victory.

Comment: Yeah I declared after victory. Cheers!

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad Awesome!